# Check to see if div hasClass, if yes, then addClass to a different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, addclass

I have a list of items that are selectable using jqueryui. I am trying to check to see if one item is selected, and if so, to then add a class to a different div.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul id="selectable">
   <li id="object1" class="ui-selected">Object 1</li>
   <li id="object2">Object 2</li>
   <li id="object3">Object 3</li>
   <li id="object4">Object 4</li>
   <li id="object5">Object 5</li>
   <li id="object6">Object 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="otherObject"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#object1, #object2, #object3, #object4, #object5, #object6 {
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
#otherObject {
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   position:relative;
   top: 0px;
}
#otherObject.newClass {
   top: 50px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#object1').click(function(){
 if ($('#object1').hasClass('ui-selected')){
     $('#otherObject').addClass('newClass');
    }
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm sure I am missing something simple. Thanks!

Comment: What's not working, and what is the question ?

Comment: Looks to be working as expected http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/J9dUJ/ , what's the problem?

Comment: This code you have seems to work well. I am not sure why you are having issues. Is your jQuery loaded properly.

See working here: http://jsfiddle.net/gL9yf/

Comment: I am not sure. It wasn't working for me before. Perhaps in the full version I had a conflict with other code. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's [slightly quicker](http://jsperf.com/hasclass-vs-is-stackoverflow/12) to use [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), rather than [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/). The following code should achieve what you're looking for:

```
$('#object1').click(function(){
    if($(this).is('.ui-selected'))
    {
        $('#otherObject').addClass('newClass');
    }
});
```

Please note that you'll also need to wrap your code inside the `DOMReady` event, so your jQuery should look something like this:

```
$(function() {  
    $('#object1').click(function(){
        if($(this).is('.ui-selected'))
        {
            $('#otherObject').addClass('newClass');
        }
    });
});
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/LrChZ/)

Comment: And would that work when the OP's code isn't working, what does it fix ?

Comment: I noticed you've added DOMReady, because otherwise the code seems just fine !

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about forgetting the DOMReady. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @ryanproject Glad to help. You might like to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery traversing should help with this.

```
$('#object1').click(function(){
 if ($('#selectable').children('.ui-selected').length >= 1){
     $('.ui-selected').next().addClass('newClass');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add some thoughts *(corrections in my opinion)* to ***@BenM*** answer.
*(of course, nothing personal, just a few things that came up reading your comments)*

#### A small correction:

> *Actually, it's **slightly quicker** to use is(), rather than hasClass().*

- Your example: http://jsperf.com/hasclass-vs-is-stackoverflow/12
- Clean compare between `.hassClass()` & `.is()`: http://jsperf.com/jquery-hasclass-vs-is

> *A test based on different conditions makes invalid.*
>   ***.is() is actually 68% slower in OP case.***
>
> ---

#### A matter of concept:

> *Please note that you'll also **need**...*

- There's no ***need*** to wrap `.click()` event in `DOMready`. It's an option, and yes, a valid one, but not the only one.

> **What the *jQuery function need*, is that the object is already rendered.**
>
> *[If .ready() is called after the DOM has been initialized, the new handler passed in will be executed immediately.](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)*
>
> So another valid option would be to put the script ***after*** the rendered HTML, like for example, at the bottom of the document and in this case, there's no need to wrap it in `.ready()` function.
>
> ---

#### A good practice:

> The use of the latest version of jQuery available or alternatively, the recommended.

- `jsfiddle` example is using 1.8.3 version.

> *There are many **obsolete functions** from that version to the recommended, which could induce programming errors.*
>
> ---

Finally, self-promoting as the accepted answer, I do not like at all, but as I say .. It's just my opinion.